# JPA CriteriaBuilder like on double

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-criteria

I'm trying to retrieve data out of a legacy database.

The column in the table is defined as a DECIMAL(13,0) containing account numbers.

The column data type cannot be changed as it will have a major impact on the legacy system. Essentially all programs using the table need to be changed and then recompiled which is not an option.

We have a requirement to find all records where the account number contains a value, for example the user could search for 12345 and all accounts with an account number containing 12345 should be returned.

If this was a CHAR/VARCHAR, I would use:

```
criteriaBuilder.like(root.<String>get(Record_.accountNumber), searchTerm)
```

As a result of the column defined as DECIMAL(13,0), the accountNumber property is a double.

Is there a way to perform a like on a DECIMAL/double field?

The SQL would be

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE accountNumber LIKE '%12345%'
```

Comment: maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363113/jpql-we-cant-concatstring-integer-eclipselink

Comment: Thank you @ScaryWombat. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have not actually tried this, but I believe it should work

```
criteriaBuilder.like(
    root.get(Record_.accountNumber).as(String.class),
    searchTerm)
```

This should generate a query kind of like this:

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE CAST(accountNumber AS text) LIKE '%12345%'
```

Comment: Thank you @coladict, but criteriaBuilder.toString() expects Expression< Character> and failed when passed Expression<Double>

Comment: @albert I edited the answer after doing some source back-tracing in Hibernate. This should work regardless what the original expression was.