# Spring Data JPA Method naming contains query for double value

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, repository

i have an entity which contains some attributes and i want to write a like (contains) query for all of its attributes with one single parameter from front controller. i have successfully achieved it for the String values but for the numeric (long, double) values, i cannot use containing keyword as it throws an exception (Parameter value ['%10%'] did not match expected type java.lang.Double()... something...).

my entity fields

```
    private String firstName;
    private double rating;
```

my repository query method

```
    List<MobileUser> findByFirstNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrRatingContaining(String value, double value2);
```

my service layer method which takes only one value

```
public List<MobileUserDTO> getMobileUsersLike(String value) {
    // parses the value and if it is not a numeric value it will be -1 (this is also a bad logic)
    Double parseDouble = (double) -1;
    try { parseDouble = Double.parseDouble(value); } catch (NumberFormatException ignored) { }
    // calls repository
    List<MobileUser> allUsersLike = mobileUserRepository.findByFirstNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrRatingContaining(value, parseDouble);
    return getMobileUserDtoList(allUsersLike);
}
```

how do i achieve this? thank you.

Comment: Are you using plain SQL or JPQL as the query language?

Comment: Probably you should use CriteriaBuilder, check this other issue out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43603951/jpa-criteriabuilder-like-on-double/43604207 and if you haven't used CriteriaBuilder before, than check this out :) -> https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: How can you use SQL's `like` expression for `Double`? Could you please describe your problem in detail so we can propose a better solution?

Comment: @sanemain JPQL query method. no Query annotation. only method name.

Comment: @Vusal i can use like query for double via a native query. it works also for int and long in mysql. but i need this in spring data jpa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use JPQL query:

```
@Query("FROM MobileUser WHERE firstName like %:firstName% OR CAST(rating AS TEXT) LIKE %:rating% ")
List<MobileUser> findByNameAndRating(@Param("name") String firstName, @Param("rating") String rating);
```

You can't use SQL `like` for `double` unless you cast it to `String`.